# Calculating AUC for DDT task with 5 data points

Tags: spss

I am trying to calculate the area under the curve for a delay discounting task using the below syntax. When I run the program, it gives me a blank column for AUC (it computes cmax, tmax, lagdelay, lagtime, etc.) but doesn't give me the AUC.

```
INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP id=1001 TO 1247.
DO REPEAT v=DDTt1ip DDTt2ip DDTt3ip DDTt4ip DDTt5ip.
COMPUTE v=UNIFORM(25).
END REPEAT.
END CASE.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.
EXECUTE.
DO REPEAT  h = h0 h1 h2 h3 h4
 / t = 0 1 2 3 4 .
COMPUTE h = t.
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.

VECTOR time = h0 to h4.
VECTOR delay = DDTt1ip to DDTt5ip.
COMPUTE cmax = MAX(DDTt1ip to DDTt5ip).
COMPUTE tmax = $sysmis.
COMPUTE lagdelay = $sysmis.
COMPUTE lagtime = $sysmis.
COMPUTE auc = 0.
LOOP #k = 1 to 5.
DO IF (NOT(MISSING(delay(#k)))).
IF (NOT(MISSING(lagdelay(#k))))
 auc = auc + (time(#k) - lagtime)*(lagdelay + delay(#k))/2.
IF (delay(#k) = cmax and missing(tmax)) tmax = time(#k).
COMPUTE lagdelay = delay(#k).
COMPUTE lagtime = time(#k).
END IF.
END LOOP.
EXECUTE.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Compare your code carefully with the original Technote (https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21476168) and you'll see that in the original there is no (#k) for lagdelay, since lagdelay is a scalar rather than a vector.

IF (NOT(MISSING(lagdelay(#k))))

in your code should just be

IF (NOT(MISSING(lagdelay)))